Gutters Frozen Solid
Not sure if this is the typical DIY question, however, we got over 50” of snow this past week. Roof and ground didn’t really have time to cool beforehand, so gutters quickly filled with snow/water and are filled with frozen ice now. Noticed water dripping through soffit vent holes, I’m thinking water is getting behind fascia. Any ideas on assisting gutters to drain and keep this from recurring? I don’t believe the downspout is clogged. Seems like heat cables or salt, but I’ve seen pros and cons for both.

Gutter heat cable/tape is a thing, although your local big box store may be sold out.

It sounds like this is not a normal occurrence where you are. Even if it is, "the ship already sailed" and it's too late now to install heat cable to de-ice and maintain gutters and down spouts free of ice. While you could technically lay heat cable over the gutter, the gutter brackets likely will hold the heat cable elevated and ineffective above the ice.
For the short term focus on eliminating the source of the water: the accumulated snow on the roof. The gutters and down spouts melt a little during the few hours of above-freezing temperatures each afternoon. Ice also can sublimate (vaporize) while temperatures are below freezing. So long as the source remains, though, new water will trickle down and the ice will continue to build.
If you really want to make an intervention, start with the down spouts with north or east exposure. These get the least solar heat during the day. Thaw them from the bottom up so that there's always a pathway for the melt to drain. Alternatively, disconnect the down spouts from the gutters so that the gutters can drain despite the spouts remaining clogged with ice.
After the current crisis has passed you'll be in a better state to decide which down spouts need heat, which gutters need heat, whether certain areas of the roof may be prone to ice damming and need heat, etc - and it'll be possible to actually do the installation.
Regarding salt: keep in mind that whatever salt you apply ends up where the melt water goes. Will it damage concrete or the yard?
